# AJax Loading Animation

Tags: javascript, pagination

please where in this script is appropriate to add a loading animation (Please wait...)
The script is a pagination script

```
var xmlHttp

function pagination(page)
{
xmlHttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
if (xmlHttp==null)
  {
  alert ("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
  return;
  }
var url="../test_sub.php";
url = url+"?starting="+page;
//url = url+"&search_text="+document.form1.search_text.value;
url=url+"&sid="+Math.random();
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged;
xmlHttp.open("GET",url,true);
xmlHttp.send(null);
} 



function stateChanged() 
{ 
if (xmlHttp.readyState==4)
{ 
document.getElementById("page_contents").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
}
}

function GetXmlHttpObject()
{
var xmlHttp=null;
try
  {
  // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
  xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
catch (e)
  {
  // Internet Explorer
  try
    {
    xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    }
  catch (e)
    {
    xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
  }
return xmlHttp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before:

```
xmlHttp.send(null);
```

you show such a message, and you remove it at:

```
document.getElementById("page_contents").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
```

because it has finished loading by then.